# Combinatorics - sending letters

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> In a group of 20 people, everybody sends a letter to 10 different people (not to himself). Are there always two people who send each other a letter?

So I'm stuck on this neat little problem. I tried looking at simpler cases, where in a group of $2n$ people, everybody sends a letter to $n$ different people. Just from fiddling around with it I reckon it isn't possible without two people sending each other a letter.

Can anyone provide help with this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw a directed graph where an arrow from a to b means a sent letter to b. The average in degree is the average out degree and this is 10. So at least one person P get letters from 10 different people and so one of the persons sending a letter to P also get a letter from P.

Comment: This is the correct idea; the average out degree is $10$, so the average in degree must be $10$.  This means that there exists a person $P$, who receives at least $10$ letters.  But, since $P$ must send $10$ letters, and there are only $19$ people who aren't himself, $P$ must send at least one letter to one of these $10$ people.

Answer (score 8):

There were $200$ letters sent in total. So at least one person must have received at least $10$ letters (because if everyone got at most $9$ letters, then only at most $180$ letters were received).

Say that Bob received at least $10$ letters. Since there are $19$ people who are not Bob, there are at most $9$ other people who didn't send a letter to Bob. Since Bob sent $10$ letters, he must have sent a letter to one of the people who sent one to him.